# How to play sound on "Ringer & Alert Volume" level

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

In my app I want to have an alarm/notification on "Ringer & Alert Volume" level.

In other words on the volume level which phone rings or alarms are used on (Preferences/Sound/Ringer and Alerts). It is different from the system volume level which changes with the volume buttons.

It should also play more than 30 sec.

I know it's possible because some clock apps can do that.

UPDATE:
OK I found an unideal solution. If use AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID and load my own sound file (aif, wav, etc no mp3 or other compressed audio) than it works.
The only problem is that it has to be 30 sec or shorter, but I can can cut it into 30sec pieces and play them piece by piece.

It does not work when on silent switch on which is a problem for me.

Code:

```
    SystemSoundID mySound;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("mySound"), CFSTR("aif"), NULL), &mySound);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
```

I suspect that OpenAL should do that. Does anyone has a simple example which loads a aif/wav file and plays it on iPhone. I found some complicated examples, but all I need is just play and stop a sound (even if it's leaking that's fine).

Comment: Hi Tibidabo, have you found the solution to use AVAudioPlayer on "Ringer & Alert Volume" yet?  I am currently having the same queries but after prolonged search I guess this is simply not possible.  Please shed some light if you have a positive solution on this.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find a solution. I used what I put in the update above, it's not ideal though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it out myself. I have to use AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID and load my own sound file (aif, wav, etc no mp3 or other compressed audio)
The only problem is that it has to be 30 sec or shorter, but I can can cut it into 30sec pieces and play them piece by piece.

It does not work when on silent switch on

Code:

```
    SystemSoundID mySound;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("mySound"), CFSTR("aif"), NULL), &mySound);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into AVAudioPlayer class. It will allow you to play sound files of any duration and you can control the volume output for the specified files you wish to play. I'm not in front of my mac otherwise I would provide code. Let me know if you need further instruction.

Comment: That's what I use. It has a volume property but it can set only the gain relative to the system volume.